# SQL query to update a column via phpmyadmin

Tags: sql

I have a large 'scores' table that resembles the following:

```
quizid    userid      score     high_score
1         john        50        0
1         bob         60        0
1         bob         65        0
1         steve       40        0
2         bob         20        0
2         bob         30        0
2         bob         15        0
```

current the 'high_score' column is '0' as it was just added.  what I need to do is make a simple query to flag this column with a '1' for every instance where a user's score for each quiz is the highest one that user has for that quiz - i.e. after running the query I should have this:

```
quizid    userid      score     high_score
1         john        50        1
1         bob         60        0
1         bob         65        1
1         steve       40        1
2         bob         20        0
2         bob         30        1
2         bob         15        0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you already tried and what is the exact problem?

Comment: pretty novice with SQL so have just searched around for the exact answer to this without luck, didn't want to try an actual query and edit the table incorrectly without being sure.

Comment: Write a query that will **output** such column. I doubt that you actually need it in the table.

Comment: i do need the 'high_score' field in the table itself updated (just a one-time run).

Comment: does this table has a unique index

Comment: @DarinHawley please check my awnser!

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure and i have not tested below code but try it maybe it  help you

```
update scores set high_score=1 where (quizid,userid,score) in 
(select quizid,userid,max(score) from scores group by quizid,userid)
```